# ¿Ejecutar una funcion al llegar a un objeto?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Me gustaría que una serie de elementos que tengo en mi página se mostraran cuando se llega a ellos en mi página, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, en un principio con javaScript, pero no se ni por donde empezar.

También se me ha ocurrido que quizás allá alguna forma de ejecutar una funcion script cuando se llegue a determinada altura del navegador.

Comment: Puedes usar este pequeña librería [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

Comment: La librería está bien, pero necesito el código jajaja

Comment: Al final de la pagina muestra el código y los CDN, no necesitas tanta ciencia para usarlo, solo inicializarlo y añadirle los atributos a los elementos que quieres animar. Así como se muestra en los ejemplos

Comment: El problema es que es para un trabajo de clase y a pesar de que he mirado los archivos de descarga, no soy capaz de encontrar lo que busco, por que al parecer importa diferentes cosas, no solo de un fichero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré las líneas de código que necesitaba para adaptar a mi gusto lo que quería.

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    var desplazamientoActual = $(document).scrollTop();
    var foto1 = $("#foto-1");

    if(desplazamientoActual > 200 && foto1.css("display") == "none"){
        foto1.css("display") == "inline-block";
        foto1.fadeIn(1200);
    }
});
```

Muchas gracias igualmente por las sugerencias!